# Serverless invoke works but curl gives error

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a serverless function, you can find the code below, and this function is deployed on aws lambda using the serverless framework. from within this function i call an external web api.

When i do `serverless invoke -f my_func` i get the expected response. but if i run a curl command it fails and i get `{"message": "Internal server error"}`

this is my curl command:

```
   curl -X GET \
  https://0wb3echzu8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/my_func \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'postman-token: 1fc551c0-7010-e1e3-7287-6a0d82d1e91a'
```

this is my code:

```
var request = require("request");
var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/',
  headers:
   { 'postman-token': '090e284e-62ad-29f0-0f10-92ae14656a37',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache' } };
module.exports.my_func = (event, context, callback) => {
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) { console.log(error); callback(null, error) }
      console.log(body)
      callback(null, body)
  });
};
```

this is the serverless.yml file:

```
service: aws-nodejs
app: sonarsic
tenant: vincent

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10


functions:
  my_func:
    handler: handler.my_func
    events:
      - http:
          path: my_func
          method: get
          cors: true
```

It must have to do something with the calling of the web api in my function. if i don't call a web api it works fine.

If I check the logs via `serverless logs -f my_func` i only get the logs of the calls that worked using serverless invoke.

what can i do to find out what is going wrong inside my function when making a curl command?

adding `cors:true` to the http section does not solve the problem

cloudwatch is attached to aws lambda but it seems there is nothing written to:
[image]

Comment: can you try to enable CORS? `cors: true`  under `http`
https://gist.github.com/shierro/0e88f5b2ada79ebd53f370e2734c0c0e

Comment: can you check the errors on cloudwatch and paste it here?

Comment: @Theo cors:true does not solve the problem and it seems that there are no cloudwatch logs

Comment: ok can you try to tail the logs? `serverless logs -f my_func -t` and try again to exeute curl? if no logs show then your endpoint does not reach the lambda function

Comment: can you also post the whole serverless.yml file?

Comment: these are the logs :
START RequestId: 7a691bc3-9d60-11e8-a8fc-e7d733dfc531 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 7a691bc3-9d60-11e8-a8fc-e7d733dfc531
REPORT RequestId: 7a691bc3-9d60-11e8-a8fc-e7d733dfc531 Duration: 65.13 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms  Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 41 MB

Comment: ok so there are logs, can you also check if there are more logs on aws console? `lambda>cloudwatch>logs>YOUR_FUNCTION` please make sure you are on the same region

Comment: can you also try `path: /my_func` please notice the forward slash

Comment: there are more logs on lambda>cloudwatch>logs>YOUR_FUNCTION but the content is similar as the one i posted before. i can't see any stacktrace that points to an error

Comment: adding the forward slash does not solve the issue

Comment: you need to console.log some error btw, silly us! `if (error) { 
 console.log(error);
 callback(null, error)
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177863/discussion-between-theo-and-vincent-claes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177863/discussion-between-theo-and-vincent-claes), we discovered that `statusCode` on the response body is missing

```
let request = require('request');
let options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/',
  headers: {
    'postman-token': '090e284e-62ad-29f0-0f10-92ae14656a37',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  },
};
module.exports.my_func = (event, context, callback) => {
  request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) { console.log(error); callback(null, error) }
      console.log(body)
      callback(null, { body, statusCode: 200 }) // response statusCode added
  });
};
```